# Flutter: Android build for deployment

Tags: android-studio, deployment, flutter, android-buildconfig

How can I create/prepare `Android` build for deployment on Appstore, using Android Studio? (I've developer account singed app and keys/credential)

What are step and checklist, required to create Android deployment build for flutter project

Comment: https://flutter.io/android-release/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have provided all the steps over here

[Preparing an Android App for Release](https://flutter.io/android-release/#signing-the-app).

And for project You can set all common settings in **pubspec.yaml** file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To build an android release of your project.

#### 1. Using the GUI (AndroidStudio)

As shown in the image below, in your Android Studio action bar click on  `build` and then select `flutter` and choose the `type of build` you want;

- ###### Build Apk

  Well, for example when you want to test your app outside of google play store.
- ###### Build App bundle

  Recommended when you want to publish your app on playstore

[image]

#### 2. Using the CLI (Terminal, Cmd )

Open the terminal and navigate to the root folder of your project and then tape the following command;

```bash
flutter build apk
```

or

```bash
flutter build appbundle
```

---

After the build you'll see a message like this :

```bash
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          191.3s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (32.1MB).
```

This means everything is fine, so go to the build folder in your project's root folder to access your final app file.

---

For more details, Please use the official documentation guidelines : https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android.